Automorphisms of non normal covering
It is known that if $p:E\to X$ is a regular covering, then by defining its deck group $$Aut(E,p):=\{\varphi:E\to E\ \ homeo\ \ s.t.\ p\circ\varphi=p\}$$
We obtain an isomorphism $\frac{\pi_1(X,x)}{p_*(\pi_1(E,e))}\simeq Aut(E,p)$ so we can compute all automorphisms of a covering map. But what we say about $Aut(E,p)$ if the covering is not regular? Is it true that if it's not regular, then $Aut(E,p)=\{id_E\}$?

Do you know a bit about Galois theory? It can help to think about the corresponding statements in terms of non-normal field extensions (this is not even just an analogy, there is a common underlying theory).

Nothing...Galois theory is not required nor covered in this course, so I should find out the answer without these extra tools

Of course, Galois theory is not needed, it's just often convenient to compare statements with a similar theory. But of course if you don't know Galois theory it's not useful advice.

Do you know the answer? At least I can try to get it using only covering theory

Hint:
A covering map $p: E \to X$ is a continuous, surjective map such that for each $x \in X$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ where $p^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of open sets $V_i$ such that each $p|{V_i} : V_i \to U$ is a homeomorphism. The deck group $Aut(E, p)$ consists of homeomorphisms $\varphi: E \to E$ that commute with $p$, i.e., $p \circ \varphi = p$. For regular (or normal) coverings, $Aut(E, p)$ is isomorphic to the quotient group $\frac{\pi_1(X, x)}{p(\pi_1(E, e))}$, where $p_(\cdot)$ denotes the pushforward map on fundamental groups. This isomorphism holds because [...]

Because the pushforward is normal so the quotient is still a group. An equivalent way is saying that the action of Aut(E,p) is transitive i.e. its orbit is all the fiber. That being said, how can I compute Aut(E,p) without this isomorphism?

If you start with $E\to X$ which is normal with transformation group $G$, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ which is not normal, try to construct a non-normal covering $E'\to X$ with group $H$.

(It should be assumed that $X$ satisfies the usual niceness assumptions when applying covering space theory.) If $p\colon(E,e)\rightarrow(X,x)$ is a connected covering, then the deck transformation group $\mathrm{Aut}(E,p)$ is isomorphic to the quotient $N_{\pi_1(X,x)}(p_{\ast}(\pi_1(E,e)))/p_{\ast}(\pi_1(E,e))$, where $N$ denotes the normalizer. In particular, $p$ is regular/Galois if and only if $p_{\ast}(\pi_1(E,e))\trianglelefteq\pi_1(X,x)$ is a normal subgroup iff $N_{\pi_1(X,x)}(p_{\ast}(\pi_1(E,e)))=\pi_1(X,x)$, so this case is generalized. The isomorphism is given by taking an element $f\in\mathrm{Aut}(E,p)$ and mapping it to the image of a path from $e$ to $f(e)$ under $p$.
You can prove this by applying the standard lifting theorems without much more difficulty than proving the regular case. Alternatively, this is a consequence of the purely group-theoretic fact that the automorphism group of $G/H$ as a left $G$-set is canonically isomorphic to the "Weyl group" $N_G(H)/H$ for any group $G$ and subgroup $H\le G$, as long as you have set up the fundamental theorem of covering space theory in a sufficiently robust manner (e.g. a categorical equivalence between the oribt category of $\pi_1(X,x)$ and the connected coverings of $X$).
